# IDEA: Code complete, browse down with TAB key

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm

I want to know if there is a way in IDEA when the code complete popup is shown that you would go down with TAB key and select one with ENTER.

For the ENTER I have figure it out: Chose Lookup Item Replace
But for the TAB i don't know how to set this up.
Any one have solution for this?

Comment: Just to clarify: instead of using `Down` you want to use `Tab` to select next item in completion popup? If so .. then I do not think it's possible as it uses standard keys .. so you would have to remap `Down` to `Tab` and it would work like that everywhere in IDE.

Comment: Yea I try to do this but Tab is then unusable in Editor (cant create tab intendation) :S

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>Tab</kbd> used to replace the string next to the caret with the selected one. It's different for <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
You can learned this for Jetbrains team designed to.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/using-suggestion-list.html